# Call the my method some amount on cocos2d

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, call, schedule

I have a method that draws a one sprite on the screen with the animation effects,
if I call in init this method

```
if( (self=[super init]) ) {
// ....
[self myMethod];
// .....
}
```

Then he does it once on my project

When I call by schedule

```
-(void)schedulMyMethod:(ccTime)dt {
    [self myMethod];
}

if( (self=[super init]) ) {
// ....
[self schedule:@selector(schedulMyMethod:) interval:0.5];
// .....
}
```

It runs for an unlimited times

I need so that I can call the my method some amount

Comment: Why would you call display code in an `init` method?  Surely you only want to start drawing when the view (or whatever this class is) is actually added to a window/superview/something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean, you want to have it repeat N times?   You'll need to keep state on times remaining for it to run.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger timesToRunMyMethod;


- (void)beginRunningMyMethod {

    self.timesToRunMyMethod = 100;   // N==100
    [self myMethod];
}

- (void)myMethod {

    self.timesToRunMyMethod--;
    // do stuff
    if (self.timesToRunMyMethod > 0) {
        // i used native delayed execution, you can replace it with whatever cocos2d offers if you want
        [self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
    }
}
```

And it's probably wrong to start this on init.  Is it a view controller?  Then you can use viewDidAppear or willAppear.